# How to get multiple count record along with other record in a single query in which group by is used

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to select total,completed and renaming data from a certain ftable in respect of certain file name, date , degree name on a condition on username if username is present counted as completed if username is not present counted as remaining

```
----------------------------------------
file_nm | degree_nm| date_nm  | user_nm
----------------------------------------
X       | D_x      |02/05/2013| USER3
X       | D_x      |02/05/2014| NULL
Y       | D_y      |02/05/2012| USER1
z       | D_z      |02/05/2015| NULL
Y       | D_y      |02/05/2013| USER1
z       | D_z      |02/05/2012| USER2
```

I want file_nm ,degree_nm,date_nm wise count total file, remaining file,completed

```
file total for x is 2 remaining for x is 1 completed file is 1
```

I am getting correct value in multiple single query but I want this as whole

> ```
> select filenm,degree_name,date_name,COUNT(*) as total
> from sameTable
> group by filenm,degree_name,date_name
>
> select filenm,degree_name,date_name,COUNT(*) as remaining
> from sameTable
> group by filenm,degree_name,date_name,username
> having username is null
> select  filenm,degree_name,date_name,COUNT(*) as completed
> from sameTable
> group by filenm,degree_name,date_name,username
> having username is not null
> ```

o/p that I want

```
filenm,degree_name,date_name,total,remaining,completed
```

Comment: That's not how you use `having`

Comment: @JohnHC Thanks john for noticing that, don't why I used that :-).My fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum of case:

```
select filenm,
       degree_name,
       date_name, 
       COUNT(*) as total,
       sum(case when username is null then 1 else 0 end) as remaining,
       sum(case when username is not null then 1 else 0 end) as complete
from sameTable
group by filenm,degree_name,date_name
```

Comment: just "," is missing after total, else every thing is working as I wanted thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
select filenm
    ,degree_name
    ,date_name
    ,total = COUNT(*)
    ,remaining = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN username is null THEN username ELSE NULL END)
    ,completed = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN username is not null THEN username ELSE NULL END)
from sameTable
group by filenm,degree_name,date_name
```

Comment: Thanks friend for your time and effort . But I am not getting what I wanted.I am getting 0 for every file in remaining and 0/1 for completed , by the way your total is coming correct.